# How to catch exceptions in an NSBlockOperation while in unit tests?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, exception, nsoperation

I'm trying to create a subclass of NSBlockOperation to catch exceptions with an alternate execution block if anything is thrown. However, in the unit tests, Xcode will not let me get passed the execution block that causes a crash despite being wrapped in a try/block either in the subclass or in the unit test. Any ideas?

It seems that this issue is specific to exceptions thrown in the context of an NSOperation since I can add the same code outside of the execution block with a try/catch without the tests aborting. Here is the relevant code:

**Subclass:**

```
// ABCTryBlockOperation.h

typedef void(^ExecutionBlock)(void);

@interface ABCTryBlockOperation : NSBlockOperation

@property (copy) ExecutionBlock catchBlock;

@end


// ABCTryBlockOperation.m

#import "ABCTryBlockOperation.h"

@implementation ABCTryBlockOperation

- (void)main {
    @try {
        [super main];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Catching exception in operation named '%@'", self.name ?: @"Unknown");
        if (self.catchBlock) {
            self.catchBlock();
        }
    }
}

@end
```

**Unit Tests:**

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "ABCTryBlockOperation.h"
#define EXP_SHORTHAND
@import Expecta;

@interface ABCTryBlockOperationTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation ABCTryBlockOperationTests

- (void)testFailingExecutionBlocks {
    __block NSUInteger result = -1;
    @try {
        NSNumber *number = nil;
        NSArray *array = @[number];
        result = [[array firstObject] integerValue];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {

    } @finally {

    }
    ABCTryBlockOperation *operation = [ABCTryBlockOperation new];
    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        result = 3 * 5;
    }];
    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        NSNumber *number = nil;
        // ======================== < Tests will not pass this line \/
        NSArray *array = @[number];
        // ========================
        result = [[array firstObject] integerValue];
    }];
    [operation setCatchBlock:^{
        result = 1;
    }];

    [operation start];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];

    expect(result).to.equal(1);
}

- (void)testSuccessfulExecutionBlocks {
    __block NSUInteger result = -1;
    ABCTryBlockOperation *operation = [ABCTryBlockOperation new];
    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        result = 3 * 5;
    }];
    [operation addExecutionBlock:^{
        result = 3 * 8;
    }];
    [operation setCatchBlock:^{
        result = 1;
    }];
    [operation start];
    [operation waitUntilFinished];

    expect(result).to.equal(24);
}

@end
```

Comment: Why you want to create subclass of NSOperationBlock instead of NSOperation? I don't see the point..

Comment: I have a specific use case, but I could do that as well.

Comment: Cocoa is not exception safe. If the exception jumps back over SDK stack frames, there are no guarantees about your environment.

Comment: Right. Any ideas then on how to accomplish this?